# Check continuity of linear functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have to check continuity of these functionals:

1) $\mathbb{R}[X]\ni p \rightarrow X p' \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ with norm $||p||_1=\int_0^1|p(t)|dt$

2) $C[-1,1]\ni f(t) \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(f(-t)+f(t)) \in C[-1,1]$ with supremum norm

My results are:

First of these linear functionals is not bounded, thus not continuous. The second is continuous with norm 1. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let denote $T$ the two linear functional.

1. Let the sequence $p_n(x)=nx^n$ then
   $$||p_n||_1=n\int_0^1 t^ndt=\frac n{n+1}<1$$
   hence the sequence is bounded but $T(p_n)=n^2p_n$ and we have
   $$||T(p_n)||_1=\frac{n^2}{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$$
   hence $(T(p_n))$ isn't bounded and then $T$ isn't continuous.
2. We have
   $$||T(f)||_\infty=\frac12\sup_{t\in[-1,1]}|f(-t)+f(t)|\le\frac12(||f||_\infty+||f||_\infty)=||f||_\infty$$
   hence $T$ is bounded.

Comment: And norm of the second functional is equal to $1$? (inequality is equality for $f=1$)

Comment: Yes, in fact by the  inequality given in my answer we have
$$||T||\le 1$$
and with $f=1$ we find that $||T||\ge1$.